# How to store different list output into a single/common list

Tags: java

I want to invoke multiple service methods from a single method that will return list of fields and i want to store them in a common pojo. How i can achieve this.

For example:

```
getAmnt(id) // returns list of fields of type List<class A>
getAddr(id) // returns list of fields of type List<class B>
```

I want to store the results into a single List. please help/suggest me. Thank you for your help.

Comment: do the classes `A` and `B` have something in common (e.g. an interface, a parent class)?

Comment: only the variables are same for A and B but both classes A and B are different pojos present in different packages and these two pojos are used by two different service classes that returns a List

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this.

```
List<Object> list_name = new ArrayList <Object>();
```

Without creating a list of specific type,create a List of type Object.You can use any list that implements the List interface instead of an ArrayList.

Create an instance of the pojo class and set the values using setter methods.

```
ClassName pojo_object= new ClassName();
```

Store the instances in the list using add() method.

```
list_name.add(pojo_object);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Its solves the OPs problem, but 
this does not really answer the question. Take a minute to read through 
[How to Answer](/questions/how-to-answer). It would benefit from some explanation of how it solves the OPs problem, consider [edit]()-ing that in?

Comment: @TimothyTruckle Thanks for the feedback :) . I would try to improve the answer.